# How to set y tick value in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

Is there an easy way to set the `axis.y.tick.values` to increase exactly by `1` up to the maximum level of dataset? I've been reading [the reference](http://c3js.org/reference.html) which states that `axis.y.tick.values`

> Sets y axis tick values manually.

How to get the maximum dataset value and set the values accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps get the max value from your data using Math.max for example.
then set the axis.y.tick.count to be half of your data set length
Let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: Yes this one helps me. I have confused a days figuring out how i can make range in my Y axis. After research and trying i have to use min and max property in my chart options. Then append d3.format after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash range function:

```
_.range(minimum, maximum, step);
```

You set min and max to min and max from your dataset and the desired step - from what you say, you want 1

I hope that's what you wanted to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/pnnscdjv/1/